# How to configure mod_bwlimited through htaccess

Tags: htaccess, apache

The mod_bwlimited module in htaccess apparently displays an error if bandwidth is exceeded.

Anyone know what options are available for configuring it through htaccess?

Comment: The source code for this module can be found here: https://github.com/CpanelInc/mod_bwlimited

Answer (score 1):

Hosting companies typically install the module to limit clients.  They don't want clients to have much control over this module through htaccess.  As a result this module is not very configurable.  Even [editing the error page to change the error message requires editing the source code of the module itself](http://seoroot.com/blog/computing/how-to-customize-apache2-mod_bwlimited-module-error-message.html).